# Which VS projects are needed for a custom QGIS build?

Tags: qgis, visual-studio

Environment:

- VS 2010
- Win 7
- QT 4.8.6
- QGIS git Src
- OSgeoW4

I have built the source for QGIS, in order to use it as a base for a custom application.
I wanted to know what projects are 100% needed, after the first build, just to make changes to the ui?

212 projects loaded in VS is a lot of memory, so any guidance would be great.